# UIImageViews Depth issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, depth

I have a strange issues with layering of the `UIImageView`s in my game. I have many `UIImageView`s which get added into the game while user is playing the game. But while game is in progress I need to modify the layering of the `UIImageview` in order to sort out depth issue.

I have tried using insert subview method to change the layering of the `UIImageView` object but no luck.

Is there any other way to sort out layering issue in `UIImageview`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `zPosition` property of the views layer.

You could make use of some of the following UIView methods:

```
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```